# Order by decimals for counts of same value

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: I have edited this question to make the query simpler:

ReportTracking:

```
Userid, ReportId, Duration, CreatedDate
```

Query:

```
SELECT t.UserId, COUNT(DISTINCT(t.ReportId)) AS ReportsRead
FROM ReportTracking t
WHERE t.Duration >= 30
AND t.CreatedDate > DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE())
GROUP BY t.UserId
```

Sample Result:

```
UserId ReportsRead
  1        22 
  2        13
  3         2
  4         2
  5         2
```

What I need to do is assign a number value to Reports Read. Essentially because there are 3 users who read swimming and they tie in terms of ranking (they each have 2 read only) I need to order them by who read the report last. I need to assign them all a decimal number value based on order of reading. So the person who read the report last would get .1, the person who read it first would get .3.

I'm not quite sure how to achieve this, the key part is that they do have have a decimal number value that ranks them and this decimal should be few decimal points long as the records are rather long. My idea was to use DateCreated and convert it a number value which I can substract from a max. But since there are multiple dates (one for each report), I'm not sure how to grab the latest one and only use that date with my report count.

Comment: what field tells us when the user last read the report?  to me you just add that to the select as `max(fieldName) as LastRead` and `order by reportsRead Desc, LastRead Asc`  ...`t.createdDate`?

Comment: @xQbert I have edited the question and simplified it even further, I want to base it of CreatedDate.

Comment: You can use `rownumber` function, partition by *ReportsRead* and order by *CreatedDate* desc

Comment: Why do they have to be decimals?  are you showing these values in your select?  kobi's response my be best if you must display these values if you just need them to order correctly then by max(date) should work; but you still may have ties and how do you handle those?

Comment: Sample data with desired output would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need to assign decimals...

Just order by ReportsRead  desc, max(createdDate) (this should be most recent read for a user in the select).

Also distinct isn't a function it's a statement.  No need for the ()

```
    SELECT t.UserId
         , COUNT(DISTINCT t.ReportId) AS ReportsRead
max(t.createDate) Asc) RN
    FROM ReportTracking t
    WHERE t.Duration >= 30
    AND t.CreatedDate > DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY t.UserId
    ORDER BY ReportsRead DESC, max(createdDate)
```

if you need the numbers and plan on displaying them

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t.UserId
     , COUNT(DISTINCT t.ReportId) AS ReportsRead
     , row_number() over (partition by count(Distinct t.reportID) order by max(t.createDate) Asc) RN
FROM ReportTracking t
WHERE t.Duration >= 30
AND t.CreatedDate > DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE())
GROUP BY t.UserId)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY ReportsRead DESC, RN
```

Comment: I ended up using the row_number as I do need the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can `rank` your rows within ReportsRead partition to obtain a ranking by ordering on the max(createddate).  [documentation: SQL Server Rank function](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql)

here is an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1eefc/11

You may simplify the query by using CTE to reuse column aliases but the concept is:

```
SELECT t.UserId
     , COUNT(DISTINCT( t.ReportId ))                                 AS ReportsRead
     , CAST(RANK()
                OVER(
                  partition BY COUNT(DISTINCT( t.ReportId ))
                  ORDER BY MAX(t.createdDate) DESC) AS DECIMAL) / 10 ranking
  FROM ReportTracking t
 WHERE t.Duration    >= 30
   AND t.CreatedDate > DATEADD(Day, -30, GETDATE())
 GROUP BY t.UserId
 ORDER BY ReportsRead DESC
          , ranking;
```